# add the new row client has entered to data source on radgirdview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, telerik

I am new to using the telerik tools for winforms and I was wondering if anyone could help me to find the best way so that the client can add a new row on the radgrid and for it to show this change on the data source.

so far I have the radgrid set up so that the client can add a new row. I just need to bind it to the data source.

```
    private void radGridView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.radGridView1.AllowEditRow = false;
        this.radGridView1.AllowAddNewRow = true;
        this.radGridView1.AllowDeleteRow = false;
        this.radGridView1.AddNewRowPosition = Telerik.WinControls.UI.SystemRowPosition.Top;

        this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.AddNewBoundRowBeforeEdit = true;
        radGridView1.EnableAlternatingRowColor = true;

    }
```

Comment: What is your data source type - List<object>, DataTable?

Comment: @checho its a DataTable

Comment: I have edited my answer below to include an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `UserAddedRow` event for `RadGridView`. This is fired after the user added a new row to the grid. You could then add the new entries to a source list or data table.

```
List<Foo> _lSource = new List<Foo>();
DataTable _tSource = new DataTable();

private void radGridView1_UserAddedRow(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.Col1 = e.Row.Cells["col1"].Value.ToString();
    foo.Col2 = e.Row.Cells["col2"].Value.ToString();

    _lSource.Add(foo);
    _tSource.Rows.Add(e.Row.Cells["col1"].Value.ToString(), e.Row.Cells["col2"].Value.ToString());
}
```

I added both possibilities in the same code snippet. Just choose one (list or table). I just created a random class to show you an example. You can create your own classes and name the properties as you want. Just note that the column (`col1` and `col2` in my example) must exist, otherwise you'll get a NullReferenceException. If you're using `DataTable` you have to add the columns once before adding rows.

```
_tSource.Columns.Add("col1");
_tSource.Columns.Add("col2");
```

I also recommend not to update the `RadGridView` properties on a click event of `RadGridView`. Because it is enough to set those properties once. Now you set them every time you click in your grid view. Either move them to the `Load` event of your form or set it directly in designer properties.

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radGridView1.AllowEditRow = false;
    radGridView1.AllowAddNewRow = true;
    radGridView1.AllowDeleteRow = false;
    radGridView1.AddNewRowPosition = Telerik.WinControls.UI.SystemRowPosition.Top;

    radGridView1.MasterTemplate.AddNewBoundRowBeforeEdit = true;
    radGridView1.EnableAlternatingRowColor = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RadGridView supports data binding to variety of data sources and CRUD operation will be handled for you automatically. Here you can find information on the supported data sources: [Telerik UI for WinForms Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-databinding-radgridview.html)

And here is how to bind to a `DataTable`, where all CRUD operations work out of the box

```
RadGridView radGridView1 = new RadGridView();
this.Controls.Add(radGridView1);
radGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("col1");
table.Columns.Add("col2");
table.Rows.Add("value1", "value1");
table.Rows.Add("value2", "value2");

radGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Here is also a [design time tutorial](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/populating-with-data/tutorial-binding-to-datatable-or-dataset).